# Cannot get ccache to work with ports in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I'm new to FreeBSD (9.1) and I'm just setting up the system. One problem that I could not solve yet is to get `ccache` working. I installed it from ports and followed the guidelines in the documentation (modify `/etc/make.conf`). Compile new packages from ports works without errors but the cache is never filled, so it seems that `ccache` is simply not used.

Here is the content of my `/etc/make.conf` file:

```
WITH_PKGNG= yes
# added by use.perl 2013-01-20 01:08:34
PERL_VERSION=5.14.2

# the rest here is copied from /usr/local/share/doc/ccache/ccache-howto-freebsd.txt
.if (!empty(.CURDIR:M/usr/src*) || !empty(.CURDIR:M/usr/obj*))
.if !defined(NOCCACHE)
CC:=${CC:C,^cc,/usr/local/libexec/ccache/world/cc,1}
CXX:=${CXX:C,^c\+\+,/usr/local/libexec/ccache/world/c++,1}
.endif
.endif
```

I also tried to follow the other guidelines in `ccache-howto-freebsd.txt` and added the following lines to `/etc/csh.cshrc`, which is the default shell used by root:

```
setenv PATH /usr/local/libexec/ccache:$PATH
setenv CCACHE_PATH /usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Still no difference. `ccache -s` shows that the cache is still not filled during compilation. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: got to a port directory you want to install and type make -V CC. The result should show ccache. If not, try to remove the first if statement, i am not sure what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @arved Thanks, that solved my problem! I'll posted your comment as the accepted answer. Still I don't know the purpose of the if-statement (which I just copied).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked in early 2013. In October of that year, instructions for properly using ccache with ports [were added](https://www.freshports.org/devel/ccache/) to `ccache-howto-freebsd.txt`. In the years since then, both ccache and the ports infrastructure have been improved and are now better integrated.

Currently, all you have to do in FreeBSD 11 and up is install the devel/ccache port and put `WITH_CCACHE_BUILD=yes` in your `/etc/make.conf`, and it will "just work" for base and ports.

In older FreeBSD versions, `WITH_CCACHE_BUILD=yes` only affects ports; base still needs the `.if`…`.endif` clauses and path adjustments. The precise instructions are in `ccache-howto-freebsd.txt` and should be easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

*(arved's comment was right. It solved my problem, but I still don't understand exactly why the if statement was recommended, anyway. Thus, I post the answer as community wiki. Feel free to improve it if you know why.)*

First, find out which compiler is used:

```
 $ cd /usr/ports/devel/gdb && make -V CC
 cc
```

`cc` is the default C compiler but it should be `ccache`.

To solve the problem, edit `/etc/make.conf` and remove the if-statement ...

```
.if (!empty(.CURDIR:M/usr/src*) || !empty(.CURDIR:M/usr/obj*))`
```

... and, of course, its closing `.endif` statement. Then the problem is solved:

```
 $ cd /usr/ports/devel/gdb && make -V CC
 /usr/local/libexec/ccache/world/cc
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. A solution that works for me is the following `/etc/make.conf`

```
# added by use.perl 2013-09-06 18:26:40
PERL_VERSION=5.14.4

.if !defined(NO_CCACHE)
    CC= /usr/local/libexec/ccache/world/cc
    CXX= /usr/local/libexec/ccache/world/c++
.endif

.if ${.CURDIR:M*/ports/devel/ccache}
    NO_CCACHE= yes
.endif
```